# Does anyone have the restlet samples from the "RESTful Web Services" book by Leonard Richardson and Sam Ruby updated to restlet 2.0?

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I would like to run the samples, but they use deprecated API of Restlet and non existing API of db4o. In short, does not compile.

I am new to Restlet (and Java), so I really do not want to waste my time trying to fix the code. My hope is that someone has already done it.

So, my question is - has anyone upgraded the Restlet samples from the book to the most recent versions of Restlet and db4o?

Comment: How's that a waste? Fixing the code yourself is probably one of the best learning exercises you could do :)

Comment: I disagree. Instead of debugging the code to understand how it works, I will spend this time looking for the replacement of the obsolete code. I do not understand how it advances me.

Answer (score 3):

The example code from this REST book is part of Restlet examples distribution. The code has been updated to use non-deprecated APIs:
http://restlet.tigris.org/source/browse/restlet/trunk/modules/org.restlet.example/src/org/restlet/example/book/rest/

However, it doesn't necessarily use the best Restlet practices, as it doesn't attempt to leverage the new Restlet API features added since version 2.0

For more recent documentation, I recommend the "[Restlet in Action](http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=1121_217)" that we are finishing wri

Comment: @JeromeLouvel, I know you were one of the writers of Restlet, if you get a chance can you peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499192/creating-a-restlet-authorizer-for-fine-grained-authorization.